# Show mutiple tables on a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently storing tweets from twitter in a database and I'm storing the user fields in a separate table. I then have a foreign key which links the userid to the tweet. I'm wondering how I should show all of the information from both of the tables.

Comment: [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)

Comment: You will have to `JOIN` them on the column that relates the two tables.

Comment: This is very basic SQL knowledge.

Comment: SQL 101 : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an inner join.

```
select *
from tweets inner join users on tweets.user_id = users.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t.message, u.name, u.email
  From Tweets t, UsersInfo u
 Where t.userid = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any schema info, so I've made assumptions.

```
select tweet, date, username from tweets
join user on user.id=tweets.userid;
```